# Python function card deal

Tags: python

Write a function, deal(numhands, n=5, deck), that 
 deals numhands hands with n cards each.

```
import random # this will be a useful library for shuffling
from random import shuffle

# This builds a deck of 52 cards. If you are unfamiliar with this
# notation, check out Andy's supplemental video
# on list comprehensions (you can find the link in the 
# Instructor Comments box below).

mydeck = [r+s for r in '23456789TJQKA' for s in 'SHDC'] 

def deal(numhands, n=5, deck=mydeck):
    mynew = shuffle(deck)
    if numhands*n > len(deck):
        raise Exception('Not enough cards.')

    hands = []
    for i in range(0,numhands):
        ncards = []
        for j in range(0,n):
            ncards.append(mynew.pop())
        hands.append(ncards)
    return hands    


print deal(2)
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the function but it keeps telling me this error
in deal
    ncards.append(mynew.pop())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: please correct your indentation first !

Comment: What does the `shuffle` function do? You haven't defined that here. You're getting an error trying to call `mynew.pop`, because `mynew` is `None`. You assign `mynew` by doing `shuffle(deck)`, but `shuffle` must explicitly returns `None` or returns nothing at all

Comment: code indented correctly

Comment: shuffle is predefined function imported from python random library

Comment: it shuffles in place and returns nothing: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Comment: @akonsu As an aside, I do kind of wish they'd implement a `random.shuffled` method that returns a new shuffled object. Something like `list.sort` versus `sorted`.

Comment: @JoranBeasley couldn't that repeat elements? Maybe `shuffled = lambda x: [x.pop(random.choice(range(len(x) - idx))) for idx in range(len(x))]`

Comment: @JoranBeasley or simply `def shuffled(x): tmp = x[:]; random.shuffle(tmp); return tmp`

Comment: @purplehaze AH HA I figured out what went wrong and edited your question to clarify your code.

Comment: yeah ... I did some stuff like that ... nothing super clean though so I got rid of it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.shuffle` shuffles in place

it changes the original deck ... it does not return anything

so just use `deck`

Comment: can you expand please? not sure wat you mean by just use deck